# Confusion about Python Tornado's blocking

Tags: python, tornado, nonblocking

So I understand the basic idea that Tornado is itself non blocking with an event loop I/O, but that blocking IO operations like database access will result in Tornado blocking during those operations.

What I don't understand is why it seems that Tornado is blocking during non-blocking operations.

I have the following code in a handler:

```
class MyHandler(BaseHandler):

    def get(self):
        x = 0
        for i in xrange(0,500000000):
            x = i

        self.render("page_temp.html",
                    title="Page"
                    )
```

This takes ~20 seconds to load the page. If I open another browser window and try to load any other page, I get hung until the 20 second page loads. Could it be because both requests are from the same user?

Comment: Running through that whole for loop *is* a blocking operation. And it's a CPU-bound blocking operation, which means `tornado` can't do it concurrently across requests. You only get concurrency with tornado when you're doing non-blocking I/O. To concurrently handle requests that do CPU-bound operations (like iterating over that huge for loop), you'd need to run the for loop in a background process or thread.

Comment: What is an example of something that is not a blocking operation? Because I'm having trouble thinking of any time consuming operation that isn't blocking.

Comment: Making a call to a database using a `tornado`-friendly DB driver ([`motor`](https://github.com/mongodb/motor), for example). Using the `tornado` asynchronous HTTP client to call some external web service, etc. Basically anything that uses non-blocking I/O and is integrated with tornado.

Comment: I would recommend reading (and maybe re-reading) The `tornado` user guide, specifically the section on [Asynchronous and non-Blocking I/O](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/guide/async.html). It might help clarify things a bit.

Comment: I'm just having trouble understanding the point of a non-blocking server. If for every useful operation including basic looping you have to do some kind of threading/work-around solution then why not just use a threaded web server? Additionally, I'm confused because if I split up the for loop into 5 separate loops, my second browser still waits until the first browser's page loads. If it was locked on the first for loop it seems like the second page would load after the first for finished.

Comment: Non-blocking servers are useful for I/O-bound workloads. Most web servers don't need to do 20 seconds of CPU work per request - they're generally hitting a database or calling an external web service, and then returning. Calls to DBs and web services are I/O-bound, which means a non-blocking framework can effectively run many of the requests concurrently. The advantage of this over a threaded model is primarily around scaling; if you have to deal with thousands of connections, the memory overhead of threads becomes a problem. Non-blocking frameworks are single-threaded, so they scale better

Comment: Ok I think I understand that. It still seems like a pretty involved task to wrap asynchronous or threading around every database interaction and CPU operation.

Comment: The [`tornado` introduction](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/guide/intro.html) explicitly states it's best suited for applications requiring a long-lived connection to the user, e.g. Long polling or WebSockets. As for the second part of your question, See [this FAQ answer](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/faq.html#id2). `tornado` is single-threaded. The only way it can switch from handling one request to another is if you explicitly give control to the event loop using `yield` or by returning from the function altogether.

Comment: re: complexity of wrapping tasks, there are usually libraries which abstract away the complexity of non-blocking interactions. A database query using `motor` looks like this: `result = yield db.messages.insert({'msg': msg})`. It looks almost exactly like a synchronous query, but it never blocks the event loop. Running something in a thread is just `executor = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(8) ; output = yield executor.submit(function, args)`.

Comment: Ok that is all very helpful thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're doing a long, CPU-bound operation directly inside your handler. `tornado` is single-threaded, which means it can't do CPU-bound work in the event loop thread without blocking all your other requests. If you need to do CPU-bound work, you have to do it in a background thread or process.

In order to make this method handle requests concurrently, it would need to look like this:

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from tornado import gen
from tornado.web import RequestHandler

executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(8) # 8 Threads in the pool

class ThreadPoolHandler(RequestHandler):

    def _do_loop(self):
        x = 0
        for i in xrange(0,500000000):
            x = i

    @gen.coroutine
    def get(self):
        yield executor.submit(self._do_loop) # Run through the loop without blocking tornado
        self.render("page_temp.html",
                    title="Page"
                    )
```

By using a `ThreadPoolExecutor` to run the expensive for-loop in a background thread, `tornado` can continue to serve other requests while waiting for the CPU work to complete.

Comment: Would this work for database access as well? Or do you really need to use an asynchronous database to handle expensive database operations?

Comment: You can use this pattern if  whatever database you want to use doesn't have a `tornado`-integrated driver. Using a real asynchronous driver is preferred since it will scale better - if you need to use a `ThreadPoolExecutor`, you can only simultaneously run as many queries as you have threads in the pool.

Comment: Another quick question: does your above code run the massive for loop in 8 threads or does it support 8 separate requests, each one running the for loop in 1 thread?

Comment: 8 concurrent requests, each one running the for loop in a single thread.

Comment: One small note. I made a minor change that got the code working:

`yield execute.submit(self._do_loop)`

Comment: Ah, thanks - copy/paste mistake. I've updated the answer.